# Android Duplicate Share Buttons (Udacity Sunshine App)

Tags: android, shareactionprovider, share-button

I'm going through this Udacity Android course, and I'm trying to add a share button to the action bar. I followed all the instructions, and for some reason I'm seeing 2 share buttons! Here is the code on github 
https://github.com/sayo9394/Sunshine

[image]

here is the diff between the 2 commits that resulted with the 2 share buttons.

https://github.com/sayo9394/Sunshine/compare/master@%7B1Day%7D...master

Comment: Can it happen that you inflate the menu twice: in Activity and in Fragment?

Comment: check https://github.com/sayo9394/Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sayo/android/sunshine/ForecastFragment.java

Comment: please check dobackground

Comment: @Egor I've checked if i'm inflating the menu twice. In the Activity i'm inflating a detail.xml which has a Settings options. In the fragment, I'm inflating the detailfragment.xml which has the sharebuttons.

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, I don't understand what the doInBackGround in the ForecastFragment has anything to do with the DetailActivityFragment where the menu is being inflated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the layout activity_detail.xml. I had it declared as a Fragment.

Changing it to a FrameLayout did the trick.

Thanks guys.